# Sending nested dictionary as data in a curl request

Tags: curl, flask

I am trying to send a post request to flask view on my local system located at `127.0.0.1:5000/login`. When I try to send a nested dictionary as data in a `curl` request this way:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"a":"b", "e":{"c": 12}}' localhost:5000/login
```

it works fine, but when I try it this way:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"a":"b", "e":{"c": 12, {"f":22}}}' localhost:5000/login
```

it does not seems to find the `{"f":22}` part in the key `e`. Any pointers on whats wrong here?

Comment: your json data type is incorrect

Comment: should be something like `{"a":"b", "e":{"c": 12, "d":{"f":22}}}` or `{"a":"b", "e":[12, {"f":22}]}`

Comment: Oops, don't know how did I miss that. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `content-type` as json. The correct method should be something like

```
{"a":"b", "e":{"c": 12, "d":{"f":22}}}
```

for your request body for data to be parsed according to what you want.